# How can I make a Cooldown in PHP?

Tags: php

I am working on a Minecraft Alt Generator, but I do not know how to make a cooldown for it (30 minutes). I also need it to display a message if the player attempts to reload the page (how the generator works). Here is the code I currently have:

```
<?php

session_start();
$lines = file('http://pastebin.com/raw/**********');
echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The only reliable way to do this is to have users register and login to your website. Then use a database with a datetime column. As long as the last time the Generator was used is less than 30 minutes ago, don't allow them to use it again. Then all you have to do is set the column to the currect datetime everytime the Generator is used.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it be possible with cookies? I know that if the user changes their browser they would be able to avoid cooldown, but still...

Comment: Sure, but it's very easy to just delete the cookie from the browser and use the Generator again.

Comment: Okay, I think a sign in would be better after thinking about it

Comment: Anyway, using cookies it's very easy. After Generator use just do: `setcookie("GeneratorUsed", 1, time()+1800);` Then have your Generator page use: `if(isset($_COOKIE['GeneratorUsed'])){ echo "Sorry, you can't use the Generator yet."; } else { ... Generator code here ... }`

Comment: Keep in mind that in Europe you're required to ask permission for setting Cookies by law!!!

Comment: Okay 0-0 Thank you for telling me before it was too late